# Using logical AND/OR with fuzzy match markers in Karate

Tags: karate

In karate, is it possible to construct logical AND/OR constructs with fuzzy match markers? Something like:

```
* def response = {a:1, {b:null, c:2}}, {a:2, {b:[x,y,z], c:3}
* match each response == {a:'#number', {b:('#present' && ('#null' || '#array'), c:'#number'}
```

Basically, checking that the key `b` is *present* ***AND*** is value is *null* ***OR*** an *JSON array*

Comment: That is an example/bogus response simply to help communicate the intent of what the question is asking about. Bottom line is that I can possibly get a response that has a nested key with a value that could be either a null or JsonArray.

Comment: Valid JSON:[
   {
      "timestamp":1510967081343,
      "changes":[
         {
            "op":"add",
            "value":{
               "id":[
                  "2c918083588e2ab20158b721f8f308e6",
                  "2c918084594c27cf01596a0f05a60297"
               ],
               "type":"accessProfile"
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "timestamp":1501118375038,
      "changes":[
         {
            "op":"remove",
            "value":null
         }
      ]
   }
]

Comment: not MCVE, try again: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - is it so hard to edit your simple JSON ? I'm not trying to be un-helpful, the best way to answer questions is to paste your example into a REAL script and try it out, so please try and respect that.

Comment: I've been trying things out. I'm simply asking the question about the tools ability to support a construct like ('#present' && ('#null' || '#array'), and if so, what would be a valid syntax? I haven't been successful in any of my attempts so far, nor have I found anything in the docs giving me any hints to what else I might be able to try.

Comment: Peter, I don't understand why you are taking such a defensive posture. This was a legitimate question. Your supplied answer was all I was looking/hopeful for. I don't understand why you couldn't have provide that in the first place.

Comment: that's already explained above, but no worries - one day you will understand when you have to answer similar questions (hopefully)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you break your match into 2 steps to avoid over-complicating things:

```
* def response = [{ a: 1, b: null, c: 2 }, { a: 2, b: [x, y, z], c: 3 }]
* match each response contains { b: '#present' }
* match each response == { a: '#number', b: '##array', c: '#number' }
```

You can combine a "marker" and a "self" reference - see the last example here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#self-validation-expressions

```
* match each response == { a: '#number', b: '##array? _ != null', c: '#number' }
```

For completeness, here is another option. Note that the `isValid()` function is re-usable, and needs to be defined (globally) only once.

```
* def isValid = function(x){ return !x || karate.match(x, '#array').pass }
* match each response == { a: '#number', b: '#? isValid(_)', c: '#number' }
```